# restoring database and re-importing aspnet membership data

Tags: database, synchronization, automation, passwords

I have a question about restoring databases that contain aspnet membership tables/data. Here’s my scenario:
I have 2 databases, staging and production. Users are generated a password in staging, and then eventually once they move to the production database they are generated a new password which is always different from the one that they used in staging (both databases live on different servers).
I want to update the staging database with a backup of the production one (to keep schema/objects in sync etc), however that would mean having to regenerate passwords for users on staging but not yet on production and that would cause hassle – is there an easy way I can somehow export the data from staging before I do a restore, and then re-import it afterwards to avoid loosing username/password data?